# My problem in understanding Head First's JavaBean explanation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, attributes, javabeans

I am reading Head First Servlets and JSP, where one servlet had code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    foo.Person p = new foo.Person("Evan");
    req.setAttribute("person", p);

    RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
}
```

Later on, they showed how to use `<jsp:useBean>` and `<jsp:useProperty>` to get person's name:
[image]
[image]

I thought I understand it - if there isn't attribute at **request** scope means variable *person* will be null, which also means **new** Person object using default constructor will be made. Bottom line: I won't have my attribute. Luckily, I previously stored Person object at request's scope, meaning it will find it.

So I wanted to try it out and change code a little. Instead of `<jsp:useBean id="person" class="foo.Person" scope="request"/>`, I typed `<jsp:useBean id="person" class="foo.Person" scope="application"/>`. Remember that our attribute is previously stored at **request**'s scope and not **application**, meaning *person* will be null. To my surprise, it easily found the attribute and printed `Evan`. How did it happen, when book clearly showed that it will search for attribute at the **same scope that I wrote in scope's attribute**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key takeaway is that `<jsp:useBean>` can also create an object if it does not find one in the scope you specified. That means that:

- if the object is not in the scope you said it was, `<jsp:useBean>` will create a new object.
- if the object is in the scope you said it is, `<jsp:useBean>` will use that object.

In other words, you can deal with one object or with two, depending in which context you placed the object, and in which context you say it is.

I know, it's confusing. So let's play with some examples. I'm going to butcher the Person class a bit to show where objects get created.

```
package test;

public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("Just to see what's going on");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            for (StackTraceElement ste : ex.getStackTrace()) {
                System.out.println(ste.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        }
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

### First example: scopes match

Servlet content:

```
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        
        session.setAttribute("person", new Person());
        
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

test.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="person" class="test.Person" scope="session" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Accessing the servlet will cause this output:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
test.Person.<init>(Person.java:8)
test.TestController.doGet(TestController.java:21)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Look at the first two lines and you will see only one object is created, inside the servlet. The `<jsp:useBean>` just retrieves this one.

### Second example: scopes do not match

Servlet stays the same:

```
public class TestController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        
        session.setAttribute("person", new Person());
        
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The JSP now uses application scope, instead of session scope where the actual person is located:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="person" class="test.Person" scope="application" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is now this:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
test.Person.<init>(Person.java:8)
test.TestController.doGet(TestController.java:21)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
test.Person.<init>(Person.java:8)
org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:71)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
test.TestController.doGet(TestController.java:24)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

You now have two objects. One created by the servlet, as in the first example, but also another one that gets created by the JSP's generated servlet, because `<jsp:useBean>` couldn't find an object in application scope, so it used the `class` attribute to create one.

**The confusion is caused by `<jsp:getProperty>` which searches for an object in scopes `page > request > session > application`, until it finds one. This is separate from what `<jsp:useBean>` does (as described above with the two examples).**

When in doubt, refer to [the JSP specs](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-eval-spec/JSP2.3MR.pdf).

With that being said, note that `<jsp:useBean>` and `<jsp:getProperty>` aren't really very much used in practice. People use the [JSP expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), or other (more powerful) custom tags. For the purpose of learning from a book and avoiding to use scriptlets (that are a bad practice), these are fine to get you started, but in practice they are not really people's favorite way of accessing objects and their properties.

Comment: Another one of your great answers! Appreciate it a lot Bogdan. Can you tell me why do we even write `scope` that we want inside <jsp:useBean>, when it is always trying to "find it" anyways?

Comment: `<jsp:useBean>` will try to get the object from that scope (it's a getAttribute, not a findAttribute), but if it then fails, it creates an object and saves it into that scope. Read very carefully the explanation from the image you posted in your question (inside the synchronized block, which BTW is another reason to specify the scope, to have something to synchronize on). `<jst:getProperty>` does the findAttribute. Once again, it's two tags you are dealing with here, that work their own way, and do their own thing. Putting them together was the confusing part.

Comment: Thank you again, I understand it completely now. I have one core thing to ask and I am leaving you alone ;) Why is there fuss about `<jsp:useBean>`, when `<jsp:getProperty>` doesn't care who made a Person object? **All it does is search for an object**. And why do I have to have same **value** as *name* in `<jsp:useBean>` and *id* in `<jsp:getProperty>` for this to work? Shouldn't `<jsp:getProperty>` call findAttribute() regardless, as all it does is literally that? Hope you understood me :/

Comment: @Stefan: I saw you asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524361/why-i-cant-use-jspgetproperty-without-jspusebean) about this, so I [answered there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65524361/why-i-cant-use-jspgetproperty-without-jspusebean/65529217#65529217)

Answer (score 2):

Check the following description of `<jsp:getProperty>` from [JavaServer Pages™Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-eval-spec/JSP2.3MR.pdf)

> The value of the name attribute in jsp:setProperty and jsp:getProperty
> will refer to an object that is obtained from the pageContext object
> through its findAttribute method.

And now, check the description of `findAttribute` in the same document:

> Searches for the named attribute
> in page, request, session (if valid), and application scope(s) in
> order and returns the value associated or null.

Thus, if the attribute, `person` is not found in the `request` scope, the search is expanded up to `application` scope.

`<jsp:useBean id="person" class="foo.Person" scope="application"/>` will create a new `Person` and put it into  `application` scope if does not exist there irrespective of whether this attribute already exists in `request` scope.

When you use `<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name">`, the search for the attribute, `person` will be performed on **page** > **request** > **session** (if valid) > **application** scope(s)  in sequence and in a *find-first* approach i.e. as soon as it is found, the value is returned (i.e. no further search happens).

Since you have two `Person` objects with the attribute named as `person`: one with the name, `Evan` in the `request` scope, and another as a `new Person()` in the `application` scope, the one in the `request` scope is returned as a result of the way how `findAttribute` works.

Comment: Thanks! I read Bogdan's answer as well. Does that mean that in my case I would have two Person objects (one in request scope made by servlet and one in application scope made by jsp) ? So when I do `<jsp:getProperty>`, it would "take" object from request's scope as it is **first going to be traversed**? Because of *page>request>session>application*?

Comment: @Stefan - I've updated my answer (added some more explanation at the end). Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing I am suspicious about and confused me as well: Picture shows how **id** from <jsp:useBean> and **name** from <jsp:getProperty> are "tied". Then why do I have to use same value ("person") in this case for this to work? Won't <jsp:getProperty> call findAttribute() no matter its value in name attribute?

Comment: `name="attribute-name"` is the syntax of how attribute is declared with  `<jsp:getProperty>`. Based on this declaration, `findAttribute` will search for this `attribute-name`. The `<jsp:useBean>` uses `id="attribute-name"`. I'm not sure why the specification architects chose different names (i.e. `name` and `id`) for the same thing. Is it what you have asked in the comment above?  Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: No,no. I was referring to why they both must have same id and name, which is **value** "person". Shouldn't `<jsp:getProperty>` be stand-alone? Because it just "tries" to find attribute using `findAttribute()`. Why must it be "tied" to `<jsp:useBean>`? Because when I remove `<jsp:useBean>`, program doesn't work..